# tweets of meta questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, twitter

@StackJudaism, the Twitter account that (I think automatically) tweets news from [main], also [tweets (at least some) meta questions](http://twitter.com/#!/StackJudaism/status/118399987058085888). I assume this is an error (hence my tagging this question `bug`); if it is indeed by design, perhaps someone can explain the rationale (or change it): why would non-users of the site want to know about meta posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter account is not solely to bring in new users.  It also has value for existing members.  Not everyone is on the site all the time.  Some people might miss a great question or a great answer, and the Twitter bot highlights these.

The same goes with the meta site.  Not everyone is on the meta site as much as the main site.  Meta questions, the governance of this site by the community, could always use more attention.  A casual user of the main site may not be aware of what is happening on the meta site, yet posts here affect them.  Meta discussions being fair game for tweeting is very much [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for these reasons.

Comment: Accepting the answer since it's obviously official and thus correct, but no +1 from me, as I disagree. Sure, tweets are for site users _also_, but they're also (and especially) seen by site nonusers, such as (in the example linked to in the question) anyone reading the #discussion hashtag's feed. This seems a poor use of Twitter. (OTOH, this view is coming from a Twitter nonuser, so maybe I'm simply wrong about how Twitter is or should be used.) (This site's users who want a feed of activity can use [its built-in RSS feed](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds/).)

Comment: Perhaps for meta questions including #discussion doesn't hold as much value, but reaching people following @StackJudaism that may not be aware what is happening on meta does hold value.

Comment: Fair enough. So maybe it should drop the hashtags for meta sites?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107767